# Limits of a Sequence.

Tags: calculus

I am not able to grasp why $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n =\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n-2}$

or

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_1^na_i=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_1^{n-1}a_i =\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_1^{n}a_{i-1}$$

and other such expressions. Like these kind of things are encountered and reasoned with physics like anything added to infinity is still infinity, but infinity is nothing, it just means to grow without bounds.

How is this kind of reasoning justified rigourously ?

(also, I can't think of many examples right now. I would be grateful if someone could quote more)

Answer (score 1):

This is true for the same reason we can say that if a sequence $a$ has a limit $k$ we can say $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=k$. The existence of a limit for a sequence implies that that values of a sequence become arbitrarily close to a given value. We can then, intuitively say that the difference of successive terms in that sequence become arbitrarily close to each other (i.e. $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n-a_{n-1}=0$) and also that $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n-1}$.

This is more of an intuitive explanation than a formal proof but this could be formalized in the usual way, with an $\epsilon$, $\delta$ argument.

Answer (score 0):

This can be proven using following theorem: If $a_n \to g$ then for each increasing subsequence of naturals numbers $(s_n)$ we also have $a_{s_n} \to g$. You can prove this by contraposition.